# Login as Domain admin without network access

Tags: windows, windows-7, domain

I have a laptop which cannot access the network either by NIC or WiFi due to the error I am looking into. I don't know the local admin credentials as the last IT admin has yet to say what they are (he has now left).

I am domain admin and the laptop is on the domain.

Is there a way to login as domain admin without having network access?

Comment: Only if the domain admin credentials are 'cached' on there. Assuming its even enabled at all, have you considered using one of the many password reset disks to reset the local admin password?

Comment: No, but not a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way which is far less invasive than password reset disks. One can change the local admin password from the command prompt thusly:

```
net user Administrator %Password%
```

Only problem is getting at a command prompt. This can be done using utilities inherent in the operating system alone, and without logging on to the computer, solely by native executable interchanging. After one has set the password one substitutes the executables back and the system will not have been at all altered beyond the password change.

As this is a good old sysadmin trick for solving exactly this situation, yet arguably takes a sniff into the greyzone for what is [permissible on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) I think I'll just arm you with that information and let you go figure.

But I will ask any moderator, for instance @voretaq7 how far one may or may not go to describe this well known trick on this site. Please advice.

Comment: Ping @voretaq7 or any moderator.